# count array in PHP giving unexpected output

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, count

I have 2 following data:

```
$temp = Array
(
    [@url] => url
    [@type] => image/jpeg
    [@expression] => full
    [@width] => 644
    [@height] => 429
)

$count_total = count($temp); // gives me 5, how can it give me total = 1?
```

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [@url] => url1
            [@type] => image/jpeg
            [@expression] => full
            [@width] => 800
            [@height] => 621
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [@url] => url2
            [@type] => application/x-shockwave-flash
        )

)
this is total:2 // this is correct
```

How can I get first array count as 1?

Comment: how can it be 1 if it has 5 elements?

Comment: @gontrollez I want to make it 1

Comment: [Count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php#refsect1-function.count-examples) "only" counts the first "level" of the array, unless you use `COUNT_RECURSIVE` - A smarter way would be to use `empty();` on the first one and then set count to 1 if it isn't empty.

Answer (score 2):

The array below(given by you)

```
$temp = Array
(
[@url] => url
[@type] => image/jpeg
[@expression] => full
[@width] => 644
[@height] => 429
)
```

**have 5 values with indexes `@url, @type, @expression, @width, @height`. So it always will give you the count 5.**

If you want to get count 1. You have to do like below

```
$temp = Array(
    array(
        [@url] => url
        [@type] => image/jpeg
        [@expression] => full
        [@width] => 644
        [@height] => 429
    )
);
```

**Here `count($temp)` will give you output 1**

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the count 1

```
$temp[] = Array
(
    [@url] => url
    [@type] => image/jpeg
    [@expression] => full
    [@width] => 644
    [@height] => 429
)

$count_total = count($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     $temp = Array
     (
         [0] => Array
             (
            [@url] => url1
            [@type] => image/jpeg
            [@expression] => full
            [@width] => 800
            [@height] => 621
        )
)

 $count_total = count($temp);
```

if your array is above, you can get count as 1;

Answer (score 0):

If you got single result, you do the following:

```
$temp = Array
(
    [@url] => url
    [@type] => image/jpeg
    [@expression] => full
    [@width] => 644
    [@height] => 429
);
```

Single result:

```
$new_temp[0] = $temp;
```

Now you get:

```
count($new_temp); // get 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$temp = Array 
       (
       [0] => Array
              (
                   [@url] => url
                   [@type] => image/jpeg
                   [@expression] => full
                   [@width] => 644
                   [@height] => 429
               )
       );

$count_total = count($temp); //gives you 1
```

Problem is that in your first block of code you are trying to count number of elements of array which in second block is insido of another array.

Answer (score 0):

It is counting the amount of elements in the array. The first is giving you 5 because the array has 5 elements. The second is giving you 2 because it is a multi-array containting 2 elements (arrays).

To make it return one you can put the array inside of an array, so like this:

```
Array([0] => Array())
```

I hope this answered your question.